# How does pipenv relate a Pipfile to the entry point of the project?

Tags: python, pip, pipenv, virtual-environment

I have a question about pipenv
How does pipenv relate the `Pipfile` and the `Pipfile.lock` to the specific `app.py` file in the same directory? Is it only because it is in the same directory?

Also, I want to know. If I want to install a dependency in a specific environment, does that dependency actually need to be installed globally?
Thank you

Comment: The Pipfile’s don’t have to be in the same directory as your module. If there isn’t a pipfile in your CWD, Pipenv traverses up the file tree untill it finds a Pipfile or runs out of directories to search, in which case it will create one.

Comment: In response to your second question, dependencies shouldn’t be installed globally, that’s what working in virtual environments is all about - isolating the dependencies if one project from another.